# Pandas apply function to both columns and rows

Tags: python, pandas, function, apply

I have the the following pandas dataframe:

```
    COL1  COL2  COL3  
N1     1     2     0    
N2     2     2     1    
N3     3     2     1
```

I would like to apply a function to each column & row, where e.g.: `x[N1, COL1] = x[N1, COL1] / sum(x[_, COL1])`

The result should look like:

```
    COL1  COL2  COL3  
N1   1/6   2/6   0/2    
N2   2/6   2/6   1/2    
N3   3/6   2/6   1/2
```

I cannot simply use `df.apply(lambda x: x/sum(x), axis=1)`, because the x in this case would be the whole column... How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Best is use vectorized solution - divide DataFrame by `Series`:

```
df = df.div(df.sum())
print (df)
        COL1      COL2  COL3
N1  0.166667  0.333333   0.0
N2  0.333333  0.333333   0.5
N3  0.500000  0.333333   0.5
```

Your solution (slowier, hacky):

```
df = df.apply(lambda x: df[x.name].div(sum(x)))
print (df)
        COL1      COL2  COL3
N1  0.166667  0.333333   0.0
N2  0.333333  0.333333   0.5
N3  0.500000  0.333333   0.5
```

If no missing values in original columns:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'COL1': [1, 0, 3], 'COL2': [0, 0, 2], 'COL3': [-1, 0, 1]})
    
print (df)
   COL1  COL2  COL3
0     1     0    -1
1     0     0     0
2     3     2     1


df1 = df.div(df.sum()).replace([np.inf, -np.inf], -88).fillna(-99)
print (df1)

   COL1  COL2  COL3
0  0.25   0.0 -88.0
1  0.00   0.0 -99.0
2  0.75   1.0 -88.0
```

Comment: the first one generates NaN everywhere.

Comment: @oakca - What is `print (df.sum())` ?

Comment: a series with values, oh sometimes its 0. I know why now it generates NaNs... I think it works. My dataframe has more columns and lots of 0s that is why, I could not see the actual correct ones. Sorry about that! I will accept, when I can. TY!

Comment: @oakca - So need only processing numeric columns?

Comment: nah they are all numeric, but lots of column sums equal to zero, which generates NaN when its the divider.

Comment: @oakca - hmmm, is possible replace NaN after division? Are NANs in original data?

Comment: it is okay, I can fillna(0) after the division!